# one database, same content, two wordpress sites, different structure? or another solution to have 2 websites with the same content?

Tags: database, wordpress, web, rss

I have a WordPress site that shows posts that it gets from rss using a plugin.

I want to split the "jobs" in 2 different websites because in this configuration is not working properly (high amount of rss sources to be parsed). 
I need to set one site to get the posts, and the other to show them on a template; i dont want to have the rss plugin on the site that display the posts.

1. Is this possible using the same database, same content but different wordpress configuration?
2. Is there another solution to have 2 different databases and autoupdate one from another?
3. Any ideea other then these 2?

Thanks

Comment: This question is better suited for wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem correctly the solution will depend on what you can do to resolve this issue.

Firstly I think you only need one website the issue you have sounds like your website is displaying items directly from the many RSS feeds which will be slow, instead I would recommend creating a process to import the posts on a daily basis to then get written to your database.

This will probably take the form of a cron job on your server.
However if you don't have access to do this I would recommend creating pages in the back end that will import the rss content when you click import.

Comment: This scenario is rolling right now: 1 wordpress website, 1 rss reader, multiple cron jobs, set at different time intervals..the website display the info received by rss. Main problem: the website is performing lousy; it was tried on several VPS and optimized. If we stop the rss reader the website performs flawlessly. That's why we want to split the job in two (one for the rss job and 1 for the website itself). I was thinking that 2 websites with the same database it could be a solution, but if I need to have the same rss plugin on both websites than is not a solution.

Comment: any ideea how to auto update the database for the website that display the info? thanks

Comment: There seems no point in having 2 websites as ultimatly it sounds like you only need one.  I would say set up a cron job to read the RSS feed and then get the cron job to write the RSS contents in to the sites database.  There could be an issue with a job not completeing leaving connections and locks running on the database, i would firstly double check that all preocesses complete and nothing is left running or in a locked state